# Remote debugging of Silverlight app via msvsmon.exe is possible?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, silverlight, remote-debugging

Our Silverlight app has met one issue which can only be reproduced in ***one specific PC with IE9***(x64)(this issue can’t be reproduced in dev machine with the same version of IE),so we need use remote debugging, however, it seems not possible because it always tell me that cannot attach to the IE process (use Visual Studio 2010).
I find that http://forums.silverlight.net/t/100057.aspx/1 tells Silvelight does not support remote debugging?  Is there any update on this? Any idea to enable debugging in such scenario?